Solving KnapSack problem on D Wave hybrid CQM
I am solving 01 KnapSack problem for 500k items with the help of hybrid CQM solver of D Wave. And for comparison I solved same problem with CPLEX. Solution quality of CPLEX solver is better than D-Wave (Not Surprising) but what is surprising for me is that the Run_Time for D-Wave CQM solver (default 85 sec) is also higher than CPLEX solver (16 sec).
I know CQM solver have to sample the problem many times. But my question is Whats the point of using quantum computer to solve optimization problem if they give inferior solution in more run_time than Classical Solver.
If anyone knows how can I reduce the run_time for D-Wave then please suggest some.
